# OOP Design for Card Game Classes

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns, playing-cards

What would be the best approach when designing the following classes applying design patterns?

- **Deck** - *addCard, deal, shuffle, getTopCard, removeTopCard, removeAllCards*
- **Hand** - *addCard, removeCard, getCard,removeAllCards*
- **DiscardPile** - *addCard, getTopCard, removeTopCard, removeAllCards*
- **MeldPile** - *addCard, removeAllCards*

(The MeldPile holds all the melds in the table.)

For me, I think the `getTopCard` and `removeTopCard` are just a wrapper of `getCard` and `removeCard`, as it just get the top position of a card then pass it to `getCard` or `removeCard`.

Should I use composition? strategy pattern? or just create a another class called **CardPile** and use it as the base class of the above class? Really appreciate if you could provide a sample code on this.

Comment: The best approach is to just start writing the game rules and let your design evolve naturally.  If you have a specific question e.g. 'I am trying to implement a rule where if a player plays a card the other play must discard, what pattern should I use here?' that could be answerable.

Comment: +1 for "let your design evolve naturally"

Comment: Beware devolving "naturally occurring" classes into sub-atomic particle base classes. Class hierarchies can get way too deep with unnecessarily generic and gratuitous processing going on. You can always refactor later if your *natural design evolution* calls for a more general base from which to derive new functionality.

Comment: Is this for homework or an interview question?

Answer (score 6):

I think you can achieve what you want with a single deck class like below which is essentially a wrapper around [Stack](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Stack.html), I don't see why any particular deck/pile/hand would not want most if not all of the same methods.

```
class Deck {
    private Stack<Card> cards = new Stack<Card>();

    public Deck() { }

    public Deck(int numberOfCards) {
        for (int i=0; i<numberOfCards; i++) {
            cards.push(CardFactory.createCard(i));
        }
    }

    private void shuffle() {
        Collections.shuffle(this.cards);
    }

    public void sort() {
        Collections.sort(this.cards);
    }

    public void removeAllCards() {
        this.cards.removeAllElements();
    }

    public void removeCard(Card c) {
        int i = this.cards.search(c);
        this.cards.remove(i);            
    }

    public Card getCard(Card c) {
        int i = this.cards.search(c);
        return this.cards.get(i);
    }

    public Card getTopCard() {
        return this.cards.pop();
    }

    public Card getNthCard(int i) {
        return this.cards.get(i);
    }

    public Card addCard(Card c) {
        this.cards.push(c);
    }

}
```

The only real problem i see is with the `deal()` method and whether this should be the responsibility of a Deck? Personally I would not think so, this leads me to think that perhaps you would have a Player class and a Dealer class that extends Player and implements the logic of dealing a deck

```
class Player() {
    protected String name;
    protected Deck hand = new Deck();

    public void addCard(Card c) {
        this.hand.addCard(c);
    }

    // .....
}

class Dealer() extends Player {
    private Deck deck;

    public Dealer(int deckSize) {
        this.deck = new Deck(deckSize);
    }

    public void deal(Player[] players, int numberOfCards) {
        for (player in players) {
            for (int i=0; i<numberOfCards; i++) {
                player.addCard(this.deck.getTopCard());
            } 
        }
    }

    // .....
}
```

Comment: I Didn't really understand what a meld pile was or did sounds a bit MtG does it belong to a player? For example an MtG style game (from my brief experience playing it) the player would have a deck, a hand, the element power played cards bit, and the monster's played part all I think could be a 'Deck' though you may wish to create a base class of 'Deck' that doesn't implement methods like `shuffle()` and use that as 'lesser stacks of cards'

Comment: I agree with you regarding deal method, it shouldn't be part of a deck as dealing is dealer's behavior. A meld pile is a set of cards (Three-of-a-kind, Four-of-a-Kind and Straight) belong to a player that posted on the table.I just can't decide what to implement because most of the open source card games uses different class for Deck, Hand and Discard Pile and while the other just created a CardPile and use it as a base class.

Comment: I'd suggest start by using a single CardPile base class which would encapsulate adding and removing cards from there you can inherit it out where you might have a `Deck` which can be shuffled and 'magically created', a `MeldPile` that has it's own rules for the cards it can contain, a `Hand` which may set a maximum number of cards allowed and rules to discard. More importantly I think it would be better just to start something, avoid `patternitis` and refactor / optimise your code if or when required.